# How can I use selenium or appium to automate chrome browser on android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate the android Chrome browser on an android device (not just a webview or another browser, but Chrome browser). I thought this was possible by following this link https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android but it automates my pc chrome browser instead.

I also tried Appium, but nothing happens after the log:

```
debug: executing: adb install C:\Users\hidden\Downloads\AppiumForWindows-0.14.2\
Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk
```

And when I try to access info from the browser, I get this:

```
info: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unkno
wn server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Did no
t successfully proxy server command"},"sessionId":"666c9e4f-7653-487a-b299-959d4
000ca79"}
```

I do have chromedriver.exe in my environment variable PATH, the whole log looks like this:

```
info: Welcome to Appium v0.14.2
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:5555
   info  - socket.io started
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session
debug: Request received with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"ANDROID
","app":"chrome","browserName":"android","browserConnectionEnabled":true,"app-pa
ckage":"com.android.chrome","device":"android","rotatable":true,"app-activity":"
com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main","takesScreenshot":true,"version":""}}
info: Looks like we want chrome on android
info: Creating new appium session 666c9e4f-7653-487a-b299-959d4000ca79
info: Ensuring Chromedriver exists
debug: Pushing unlock helper app to device...
debug: executing: adb install C:\Users\hidden\Downloads\AppiumForWindows-0.14.2\
Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk
warn:  killed=false, code=1, signal=null
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status
debug: Request received with params: {}
debug: Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/status
","method":"GET"}
info: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unkno
wn server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"Did no
t successfully proxy server command"},"sessionId":"666c9e4f-7653-487a-b299-959d4
000ca79"}
GET /wd/hub/status 500 1014ms - 238b
POST /wd/hub/session 200 31311ms
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on your Android device in the developer options?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can automate the selendroid browser just fine. I think its not possible to automate chrome browser using selenium. I ended up just creating a 4.4 project with a webview and using the instrumentation tools to connect the chrome pc tools to my device.

Comment: Interesting, it is certainly possible to automate the Chrome Browser (I have done it via telemetry), but I have not tested it via Selenium

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> debug: executing: adb install C:\Users\hidden\Downloads\AppiumForWindows-0.14.2\
>   Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk

If nothing is happening here, then you must restart your ARM emulator and the appium server/chromedriver again. I came across this multiple times and noticed many a times adb shuts down and looses connectivity. If I restart abd, everything starts working. This is just a adb command to install the apk, it should take time depending on the size of the apk but not much.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities  capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.3");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
}
```

I have this piece of code which runs well on appium automating the android chrome browser. In the above log, you chromedriver has not started successfully and so the browser is not automated. I have appium log which is automating the chrome browser:
[image]
Also, every combination of ChromeDriver and Chrome APK is not working. I have been struggling this since days and found out that:
Chrome Driver 2.3 and Chrome APK 29.xxx are compatible.
Chrome Driver 2.9/2.8 and Chrome APK 30.xx or 31.xx are not working.

Regarding Just ChromeDriver:
The chromium link you mentioned will automate the PC browser if you have not set the capability. Something like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();//DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOptions("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

You have to set this capability incase you are just using chromedriver (and not appium).
I am working on this but could not find the capability.
Also you will have to start the ChromDriver by yourself on command promt which will listen at 9515 port for any automation.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up creating my own webview in 4.4 android that can connect to chrome tools. I am sure this works, because I seen the same logs you just put on other sites, but for me it just freezes at the unlock_apk-debug.apk. Restarting adb doesn't help. Also, I am using a phone, not an emulator.

Comment: If your appium log freezes at unlock...statement, you might probably have more than one connected device...Also you can simply execute this command separately with any arbitary apk file to check what is wrong with your adb.

Comment: maybe disable "app verification via USB" in settings/developer options on the device might help? also more than one device (real or emulator) might cause problems

Answer (score 1):

1) Read appium logs and see what version of chrome driver is it referring to.
2) Check online for latest chromedriver version. 
As of today latest version is 2.23. Download this for WindowsAnd extract it
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.23/
3) Upgrade Appium (latest today - 1.4.16.1)
 Now goto this location,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win

And paste the the chromedriver.exe here.(replace the old one)

4)

```
    public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> startChrome() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "AndroidDevice");
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 180);
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(appiumURL), capabilities);
driver.get("google.com")
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       return driver;
    }
```

5) In case this does not work, make sure to check in appium logs, if its pointing to the updated chrome version

Answer (score 0):

First Check your mobile device are connected with chrome browser so.
Type the below command on web browser url

```
chrome://inspect/devices#devices
```

This will show the list of devices connected.

Then set the desired capabilities.

Below is the code working for me:

```
public void setUp() {
    File app = new File("./TestingAPK/app-release-v3.1.0-c20170201.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setCapability("unicodekeyboard", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("resetkeyboard", true);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "21");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "app.mangalam.billboy");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "app.mangalam.billboy.main.SplashActivity");

    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver < > (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i setup this way and this is working perfectly.

```
      String appium_node = ("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");

    //Set the Desired Capabilities
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Mi Android Phone");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "ba689af30404"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", true);
    caps.setCapability("unicodekeyboard", true);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);

    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver < > (new URL(appium_node), caps);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This launched me the chrome browser in latest Appium 1.10

```
package com.prac.com;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Demo1LaunchChrome {

    private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator demo1");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Appium Jars\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.get("https://hobbyclues.in");
         Thread.sleep(10000);
         System.out.println("Done!");
         driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following points need to add:-

1) Add  chromedriverExecutable capabilites and give path of chromeDriver.exe

2) Write a code to switch Native_App to WEBVIEW.

```
public static void applaunch() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilites = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilites.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "MyDevice");
        capabilites.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "112udid12");
        capabilites.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "android");
        capabilites.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9");
        capabilites.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "C:/path/Of/chromedriver.exe");
        capabilites.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE ,"com.android.chrome");
        capabilites.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY ,"com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        capabilites.setCapability("noReset", true);


         AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver= new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub") ,capabilites); 
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);     

        //We use Set<String> views to get all context values.
        //And then navigate Native_APP to WEBVIEW_chrome.

        Set<String> views = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String view :views)
        {
            System.out.println("View is :- "+view);
            if(view.contains("WEBVIEW_chrome"))
            {
                driver.context(view);
                break;

            }

        }

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("userID")).sendKeys("UserOne@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("Password")).sendKeys("MyPassword");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("LoginBtn")).click();
```

Comment: your answer does not add anything to the original answer, can you explain how your answer is better than the actual accepted answer ?